# How to add a CSS class to an element on click - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How do you add a CSS class to an existing REACT element on click?

I have a JSFiddle created: https://jsfiddle.net/5r25psub/

In the fiddle, the code only works if I have the statement: `this.setState({color:blue});`

I want something like `this.setState({className: 'green'});`
What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
    <html>
    <script>
        var Hello = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {
                    color: 'blue'
                };
            },
            handleClick: function(){
                if (this.state.color === 'blue'){
                    this.setState({className = " green"});
                } else {
                    this.setState({color: 'blue'});
                }
            },
            render: function() {
                return <button className={this.state.className} onClick={this.handleClick}>My background is: {this.state.color}, Click me to change</button>;
            }
        });

        React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));

    </script>
    <body>
    <script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>
<style>
.green {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.blue {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
</style>

    <div id="container">
        <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Inside `handleClick` you wrote `className = " green"` but it should be `className: "green"`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the module `classnames` found here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

So you would do something like:

```
getClassNames() {
    return classNames({
        'blue':  this.state.clicked,
        'green':  !this.state.clicked
    });
},
render () {
    return <button className={this.getClassNames()} onClick={this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})>
}
```

Comment: nice, didnt know about that, always just coded that in myself, prob still will though. lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to add all state parameters to `getInitialState`, right now the only thing you have is `color`, so `this.state.color` is the only thing in there

When you set your state to className: something, that is the only thing in there now, even color is gone...and that is why the initial color is the normal bland gray

you have a syntax error in setState as well, its not

```
this.setState({className = " green"});
```

It should be:

```
this.setState({className: " green"});
```

Finally, `React.render` is deprecated, you need to use `ReactDOM.render` now

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/69z2wepo/36597/

Comment: I am a bit confused on how do I retrieve the classList. Does element.getClassList() work in React? Or is there an other way to do so ?

Comment: why do you need a class list? Take a look at the code in the fiddle I posted, you had the incorrect external resources, open up the console and see what it says, thats all it took for me to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/ajvf50s6/3/

Most probably, you should better do a verification based on the `className`, not on the `color` state property:

```
handleClick: function(){
    if (this.state.className === 'blue'){
        this.setState({className: "green"});
    } else {
        this.setState({className: "blue"});
    }
}
```

Also, as @Omarjmh mentioned, you have a typo in your code. `{className = " green"}` is wrong assignment.

Comment: Perfect! This definitely helps. I had a followup question - How do I add a css class to an existing element which already has classes.

For example, an element <div class="green"></div> , I would like to add the class centre_align to it such that it now looks:

<div class="green centre_align"> </div> 

Is that possible ?

Comment: Also, this is one for single element. would it be necessary to preserve states for multiple elements?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using two state variables, you can do like this.

Since the initial state of color is blue, you can change the handleClick function as :

```
handleClick: function(){
 if (this.state.color === 'blue'){
  this.setState({color : "green"});
 } else {
   this.setState({color: 'blue'});
 }
}
```

And, for the className, consider a variable :

```
let colorClass= this.state.color === "blue" ? "blue" : "green"
```

Now, replace the className as below and you need to enclose that object where you call **div** class.

```
return <button className={colorClass} onClick={this.handleClick}>My background is: {this.state.color}, Click me to change</button>;
```

I hope it works fine.