# How to add a class to a clicked list item

Tags: reactjs

Can someone help me add a class to a list item on a click event? So far I tried it by accessing the `refs` attribute:

```
<li className="existing-class" refs={ name }  onClick={ this.sort.bind(this, name) }>Foo</li>

@action sort = (name) => {
  this.refs.name.className="existing-class another-class"
}
```

However, this is not working.. can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317933/how-to-add-a-css-class-to-an-element-on-click-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to patch your existing solution, try properly accessing the dynamic `name` property: `this.refs[name].className="some-class"`.

But for a more React-y solution, you should store state in the `li`'s parent component as to whether it's been clicked, and then set the `className` based on the parent's state.

Comment: OK, i don't believe it affects my answer at all.

Comment: still not working.. i tried `this.refs[name].className="existing-class some-class` but `some-class` didn't get added on for some reason...

Comment: So try the other method, of storing state. That's really the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

right, the proper way would be to have the element's class controlled by `state`, rather than by the click event.

e.g. `<li className={'existing-class ' + this.state.clicked ? 'some-class' : ''}>Foo</li>`

and have your `onClick` function do `setState({clicked: true})`