# How to dynamically change styling of a dynamic piece in react (using functional components)?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

TLDR- I want to change the backgroundColor of 1 square onClick. I am not sure how to differentiate this 1 square from the other 63 since they are created dynamically

I am dynamically creating a Board composed of 64 squares and I want a square's background color to change if selected under the proper conditions (preferably under the selectPiece function) and then revert back after a move is made or the piece on the square is unselected. My problem is identifying the dynamically created square to change its state.

Board.js

```
    let [squareStyle] = useState('squares ');

    function Row(i){
        const newRow = [];
        let count = i * 8;   
        let squareImp;     
        for (let j = 0; j<8; j++){            
            if ((i + j) % 2 === 1){                
                squareImp = squareStyle + "g";
            }else {
                squareImp = squareStyle + "y";
            }
                newRow.push(<div key={count} id={i * 10 + j} className={squareImp} onClick={isMove ? selectMove : props.data[count].name !== null ? selectPiece : undefined  }>
                     { (props.data[count].name != null) &&
                        <img src={images[props.data[count].name]}
                        className="icons"
                        alt="chess piece" />    
                    }
                </div>)            
            count++;
            
        }
        return <div className="rows" key={i}>{newRow}</div>;
    }
```

If I was using class based Components, then I could use this.setState to change the individual square, using something like -

```
this.setState({className: "squares b"})
```

but with Function Components, the setState is unique to each property. So while I can use the id (currently not used for CSS) to grab the selected square, I can't create a [state, setState] variable for each square. Is it possible to dynamically create a variable? aka something like

```
function setBackground(int id){
    let StateChange = id + ""
    setStateChange({backgroundColor:"blue"})
```

It doesn't seem to be.

So after I have spent quite a bit of time reading the multitudes of posts on here about how to dynamically change the CSS in React I tried following the only article that I thought might apply to me here- [How to add a CSS class to an element on click - React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317933/how-to-add-a-css-class-to-an-element-on-click-react) and set the className with a function like so -

Board.js

```
    function Row(i){
        const newRow = [];
        let count = i * 8; 
        for (let j = 0; j<8; j++){          
                newRow.push(<div key={count} id={i * 10 + j} className={getClassName(i, j)} onClick={isMove ? selectMove : props.data[count].name !== null ? selectPiece : undefined  }>
                     { (props.data[count].name != null) &&
                        <img src={images[props.data[count].name]}
                        className="icons"
                        alt="chess piece" />    
                    }
                </div>)            
            count++;
            
        }
        return <div className="rows" key={i}>{newRow}</div>;
    }
    //function getClassName(e, i, j){ //can't read e
    function getClassName(i, j){
        console.log(i, j)
        //console.log(e.currentTarget)
        let base = "squares ";
        if (clicked){
        // if (clicked && e.currentTarget.id == i * 10 + j){ //this is what I want but I can't figure out how to grab the target to compared the id to          
                 return base + "b";            
        } else {
             if ((i + j) % 2 === 1){                
                 return base + "g";
             }else {
                 return base + "y";
             }
        }
    }
```

but as you can probably tell from the commented out text, I can't figure out how to grab the event and thus use the id to compare so that I am only changing the background color of the selected square rather than the whole board.

I don't understand the nuances of event handling but I am guessing that because I am calling the function from within the className attribute of the div element rather than from the element itself, that the event just isn't available. I am not sure how to get around it.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So do you want to have some global state that has the id of the component which is mapped to its style?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to solve my problem, if it is able to take in the id as a parameter and I don't have to set 64 key's beforehand.

Comment: So qq why wouldn't you create a new component called Square that you use to create the rows. Then in that component have each of them responsible for their own state.

Comment: Hmmm. That was my original set up, I forget why I changed it, but I believe it was just a matter of convenience. It would be a lot of refactoring to add this final feature but that would do the trick. I think that may be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this would be how I would do it. I abstracted Square to be its own component and it is being create via your for loop. Each of these Squares can manage their own local state so when they are clicked they can update their own state and you dont need to have messy centralized code.

FYI you seem to be using `useState` incorrectly as it does have its own function to update its local state. The below code is not 100% correct as Im not sure what you are doing, but it should give you a general outline.

I would also review the React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Just so you can get clear about the `useState` hook and how it can be utilized.

```js
const { useState } from 'react'

const Square = (i, j, data, count, isMove, selectMove) => {
    const [ squareStyle, setSquareStyle ] = useState('square') // then use setSquareStyle('STYLING) to update local state
    const selectedPiece = data[count].name
    return (
        <div key={count} 
        id={i * 10 + j} 
        className={getClassName(i, j)} 
        onClick={isMove ? selectMove : selectedPiece ? selectPiece : undefined  }>
        { (selectedPiece.name != null) &&
            <img src={images[props.data[count].name]}
                className="icons"
                alt="chess piece" />    
        }
        </div>
    )
}




function Row(i){
    const newRow = [];
    let count = i * 8; 
    for (let j = 0; j<8; j++){          
            newRow.push(
                <Square 
                    i={i} 
                    j={j} 
                    count={count} 
                    isMove={isMove} 
                    selectMove={selectMove} 
                />
            )            
        count++;
        
    }
    return <div className="rows" key={i}>{newRow}</div>;
}
//function getClassName(e, i, j){ //can't read e
function getClassName(i, j){
    console.log(i, j)
    //console.log(e.currentTarget)
    let base = "squares ";
    if (clicked){
    // if (clicked && e.currentTarget.id == i * 10 + j){ //this is what I want but I can't figure out how to grab the target to compared the id to          
             return base + "b";            
    } else {
         if ((i + j) % 2 === 1){                
             return base + "g";
         }else {
             return base + "y";
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I avoided using the setState function for the class name since a change in state triggers a re-render and it is used 64 times. Is there a reason why it should be used instead of a 'let' variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58860021/why-react-hook-usestate-uses-const-and-not-let#:~:text=const%20is%20a%20guard%20against,reference%20within%20the%20same%20scope.&text=It%20does%20not%20mean%20the,variable%20identifier%20cannot%20be%20reassigned.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am asking - Is there a benefit to using the setState function to change the value of the class name? The downside is 64 extra, unnecessary re-renders. Is there a good reason I should do it anyways?

Comment: Hey it really depends if the style is going to be dynamic or not. If a style is updated then there would probably have to be some kind of re-render of the component.  So your not having 64 re-renders because it is siloed to that component. So the re-render only happens for that specific square.I think this is the best way to do it especially if you utilize useMemo or something to get better cache performance, but I dont know everything so it might take a bit more research.